# Windows 7 Single Sign on WiFi causing user selection to show up

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I have been looking into a problem on our network where users machines do not load all of their settings and group policy when not connected to Ethernet on a laptop(even to the point of not being able to log on if a local profile has not first been created) I have found that by enabling WiFi Signal Sign on that user is able to login to the Wi-Fi first then connect to the domain and login However this causes the user to see a list of users on the machine after pressing Ctrl + Alt + Delete. If no user has been logged in it will show Other User for them to login to the domain with.

How do I make it return to normal(so it auto selects other user or the user who is logged in) with out turning off WiFi single sign on or is this something that will just happen.

[image: WiFi Single Sign on settings]

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: Sorry about that was in a little rush have updated the question but ill add it here in case How do I make it return to normal(so it auto selects other user or the user who is logged in) with out turning off WiFi single sign on or is this something that will just happen.